# How to publish a SAFE template application to a website/hosting service

Tags: web, f#, publishing, f#-fake, fable-f#

I have made a website in the safe template using F# and I am currently attempting to publish it to a hosting service/domain.

I have already uploaded all the project files to the index_html folder using the built in FTP provided by the hosting service. And I am unsure about the next step.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Uploading files to index_html is what you do when your hosting service will be serving the files with its own Web server (e.g., Apache). What you need to do is set it up so that requests to your site will be forwarded to the *SAFE app's* web server. The details of how to do that vary widely between hosting services, and some of them don't allow it, so we'll need more details in order to answer your question. What hosting service are you wanting to use? And what are that service's instructions for setting up your own ASP.Net Core server to serve your site?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little wide but as rmunn infers, it's possible your hosting service is designed for a static site.

If I'm making no sense here, I'd head to the Safe Stack docs on Github, read the pages about registering with Azure, then follow the steps to `Deploy to App Service`. This will give you a much better feel for the sort of hosting arrangement you'll need when deploying the app, and obviously you're not confined to using Azure in the long run. Easiest to start a new template from `dotnet new SAFE --deploy azure` and get the deployment process working, then retrofit it to your app afterwards I reckon.

Of course if you only need a static website and don't actually have any requirement for an API / DB etc., fable-elmish could work...